# SpringBoot CloudStream (Kafka) and JPA

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-orm

I have built an application which receives data requests via kfka and uses JPA to persist data, on every JPA error for example

```
Exception in thread "user-4db12638-e58b-4728-9374-886ef20d0f31-StreamThread-1" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_sb8bbouer5wak8vyiiy4pf2bx]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Is there a mechanism with which this can be prevented and errors better handled. I am using KStream Handler in my StreamListener.

My application properties has;

```
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=input
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=user
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=application/java-serialized-object
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.header-mode=raw
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.use-native-decoding=true
 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enable-dlq=true
 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.dlqName=errors
 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.autoCommitOnError=true
 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.autoCommitOffset=true
```

and Processor is

```
@StreamListener(target = "input", copyHeaders = "true")
@SendTo("output")
public KStream<UUID, Event> process(KStream<UUID, Event> stream) {
    return stream
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<UUID, Event>(k, processEntity(k,v)))
            .peek((k, v) -> {
                log.debug("Processing {} {} {}",k, v.getPayload(), v.getException());
            });
}

private Event processEntity(UUID key, Event event) {
        User user = userRepository.save((User) event.getPayload());
        event.setPayload(user);
    return event;
}
```

As i read spring cloud stream docs Excetpion handling; this will cause any runtime Exceptions, in particular **"DataIntegrityViolationException"** to be serialised to topics **"errors"** using following

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

but i never see any message received by;

```
@KafkaListener(id = "junit", topics = "errors")
public void receieveErrors(Message<?> errorMessage) {
      log.debug("DLQ:  {}" + errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception in the handler using the processor API and send the offending record to a DLQ. See [this section in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_handling_non_deserialization_exceptions) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko, I did found that, but was unable to configure it/ make it work for me. I have two topics input and output. Where input send data processed by listener and if sucessful send it back to output. in theory an errored data messages should be put back onto third topic with an expcetion/error trace.

Comment: You want the record that failed due to this constraint violation to go to a separate topic so that you can process that later, correct? If so, then the DLQ approach should work. Where does it not work for you?

Comment: i have updated question to give you more insight, if you can help me on that